# lwjgl creating a 2d world with camera

Tags: java, 2d, lwjgl, viewport

I'm familiar with Java but I'm new to Java game development, and I have a few questions about the 2d game I'm making:

1. How do I make a camera that follows the player?
   I know it's something with glViewport and glTranslate but when do you call them?
   glViewport in the initGL() and glTranslate in the gameloop?
2. How do I create a world?
   I haven't tried anything yet because I don't know where to start.

Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you take a look and try a game engine. [Jme3](http://www.jmonkeyengine.org) is a very good java game engine that uses lwjgl and has builtin functionality for creating worlds (a world would typically be an abstract class) and different types of cameras and camera movement.

jme3 is BSD-licenced so you can take it, use it and even sell your game that includes the engine (whereas with a GPL licence you may not do that).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [LibGDX](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) it's an library that uses LWJGL natives to manipulate OpenGL, its realy noob friendly. It has allot of camera stuff built in that can be reused and customized. It also gets updated every day (at least the nightlies do), and there is allot of online support for it.